# Chrome extension desktop notification show 2 time

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm create a chrome extension with desktop notification, everything is fine but for each record 2 notification shows I used tag for prvent the issue popup shows on notification but my music function play twice.

```
function sender()
{
console.log('ww = ' + list );
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
console.log('lenght = ' + list.length );
if (list[i].sent == false) 
{
console.log('again');
music();
list[i].sent=true;
var link = '#'+list[i].key;
var notification = new Notification(
list[i].title, {
icon: 'ico.ico',
body: ""+ list[i].key,
tag:"uniqueTag"
});
notification.onclick = function () {
window.open(link);      
};
console.log('ddd = ' + list[i].sent);
}
    }
  }
```